# Is Universal link work on HTTP server?

Tags: iphone, ios9, xcode8, ios10, ios-universal-links

1. Guys, just want to know whether Universal link can work with HTTP website instead of HTTPS.
2. If i use universal links in **www.mydomain.co.id/match/play_2.html**
   Entitlement setting is **applinks:kumpul.co.id** right? But for the apple-app-site-association, i upload it to **http://www.mydomain.co.id** ,

   ```
   {   
     "applinks": {
     "apps": [],
     "details": [
           {
               "appID": "[TeamID].id.co.mydomain",
               "paths": [ “match/*”]
           }
     ]
     }
   }
   ```

so the location will be **http://www.mydomain.co.id/apple-app-site-association**. Is it the right configuration ?

3.For debugging information, how could i see my log in iphone when debugging via Xcode to check my code is correct? because when i click links from Whatsapp for example, i can't see the the log in my console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Universal Links URLs can be either `http://` or `https://`. *However*, the apple-app-site-association file MUST be served over HTTPS otherwise iOS will refuse to scrape it.

This scraping happens only when the app is first installed, and during updates installed from the App Store. Not for every link open. If the scraping attempt fails, you will see an error like this in the OS-level (*not* App-level in Xcode) logs:

```
Sep 21 14:27:01 iPhone swcd[2044] <Notice>: 2015-09-21 02:27:01.878907 PM [SWC] ### Rejecting URL 'https://examplecustomdomain.com/apple-app-site-association' for auth method 'NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust': -6754/0xFFFFE59E kAuthenticationErr
```

Comment: ok, so trace this error logs, i must see the log from Xcode - window - device right? There are so many logs in every seconds in this menu

Comment: That is the place, yes. It's tough to catch — you'll probably need to save and search for this line

Comment: ok, i have changed my website to HTTPS and passed the results from https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox, but still universal link doesn't work in my app. Even this function didn't run
application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        NSLog("Check Universal Link") 
return true 
}

I cannot see "Check Universal Link" logs in my window- device console & Xcode console

Comment: Hmm. Could you update your question with full code snippets for that method?

Comment: yes, i have created a new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693075/universal-links-doesnt-work-in-ios-10-2